# Pass an argument to the function in code behind onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

Is it possible to pass an argument to the function in code behind ?

I tried to pass it using `CommandArgument` as

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument="argument" OnClick="DeletePhoto" />
```

and access using

```
Button button = (Button)sender;
string Sl_no = button.CommandArgument.ToString();
```

But actually, the argument is, `<%# Eval("sl_no")%>`(The items are placed using asp.net listview). ie,

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("sl_no")%>" OnClick="DeletePhoto" />
```

But I was getting the error

> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.

**How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: use single quotes around your property inside the Eval `'sl_no'`

Comment: Now I get _"Compiler Error Message: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want to do the same, I am posting this answer.

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("sl_no")%>' OnClick="DeletePhoto" />
```